# Google maps location working in app but not in browser

Tags: google, google-maps, gps

I am trying to use google maps to determine my location. When I open the app on my phone (Samsung Note 4), I immediately get location with an accuracy of about 10 metres, but when I access the website  in any of the browsers on my phone (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Android stock), I see a message saying that my location could not be determined, even though my gps is on and the gps sign flashes on in the notification bar just before I get the error message. I set my phone to allow location access to all applications and in every browser I clicked accept when it asked me if I wanted to share my location. Where am I missing something? Why can't the webpage figure out my location while the application can?

Answer (score 2):

Google apps have a special setting of their own to enable location access.  Open the Google Settings app and change the Positioning Mode setting (under Location) to High Accuracy, and it should prompt you for permission.

In Chrome, go to Settings → Site Settings → Location and ensure nothing related to Google is being blocked.